# How can I make TreeForm think some elements are atomic?

Tags: graphics, trees

I want to apply `TreeForm` to some expressions of the form `m[m[m[y[1], y[1]], x[1]], z]`, but I want Mathematica to treat expressions of the form `x[i]` or `y[i]` as atoms. For instance,

```
TreeForm[m[m[m[y[1], y[1]], x[1]], z]]
```

outputs

[image: Output tree]

but I would like the leaves to be `y[1]`, `y[1]`, `x[1]` and `z`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since strings are atomic and are displayed as themselves in a tree, we can just replace the terms with their string counterparts.

```
TreeForm[m[m[m[y[1], y[1]], x[1]], z] /. pat : _x | _y :> ToString@pat]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.